# Post from one ASP.NET MVC site to another

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to post a form from one MVC site so that it invokes the POST action in a controller on another site ? I can do a GET easily, but a browser redirect is always a GET as per my understanding and I am unable to invoke the target site's POST action.

e.g. http:/siteA.com/test invokes http://siteB.com/result/signin ... in the ResultController, the Get version of the "SignIn" action gets invoked, but I need the "Post" version to be invoked as I need to pass in parameters in the POST header.

Currently I am resorting to using a GET and am passing params. using the query string which is not ideal for my scenario. Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use GET for POSTing data. Need I say more? :)

Comment: What do you want to do with the results of the post to the other site?  Do you want the user to see the results of the post or do the post behind the scene and return your own page as a result? Need to know if you should perform the post server side or client site.

Comment: Hi Todd, I don't want the user to be able to see any of the data. I am currently using query string params. which is less than ideal for me. I would like the POST so that the data the target site needs is passed via POST headers, completely hidden from the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used AJAX to invoke the target and bundled in the necessary parameters to post in there.

Answer (score 4):

You could `POST` using a simple form:

```
<form method="post" action="http://othersite.com/controller/action">
    <!-- some input fields containing the values to post -->
    <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="value1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Post to other site" />
</form>
```

Comment: I don't want the data that I am passing from siteA to siteB to be visible when the user does a "view source" in the browser.

Comment: Two possibilities: encrypt it or perform a server side POST request but in this case you won't be able to redirect the user to the resulting page.